# Do I require a runtime permission in Android 6.0 to just load the Map and show Pin?

Tags: android, dictionary

I just have to show a Pin on the Map with the static Lat-Long. Do I need to give any runtime permission for Android 6.0 & 7.0 just to load the Map and show a Pin over it ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes its needed !!

Comment: I have removed 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
from the Manifest and yet I am able to show the Pin on the Map, I have also not asked for the runtime permission anywhere.

Comment: How is it working then ?

Comment: if you are getting location of user in your application than its required to add runtime permission.
But you load map with pre-define location so no need to add runtime permition.

Comment: If you ar loading the map with predefined location , no need for permission. If you need to get device's location to show pin then they ( the poermissions) are needed.